# The stackoverflow.blog RSS feed is invalid

Tags: bug, rss

My reader application ([inoreader](https://inoreader.com)) fails to subscribe to the Stack Overflow blog.

[See validation here](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.blog%2Ffeed%2F)

> This feed does not validate.

> line 36, column 54: XML parsing error: :36:54: undefined entity

> `<title>The AI assistant trained on your company&rsquo;s data</title>`

This is the suspicious feed item:

```xml
  <item>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">a60f0d2d-21eb-4ef1-b3e6-4a438a9227b8</guid>
      <title>The AI assistant trained on your company&rsquo;s data</title>
      <link>https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/11/17/the-ai-assistant-trained-on-your-company-s-data/</link>
      <pubDate>Fri, 17 Nov 2023 08:40:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <description><![CDATA[Today&rsquo;s guest is Joel Hellermark, founder and CEO of Sana, an AI-powered end-to-end learning platform. He talks with Ben and Ryan about a polymath Renaissance, what regulation might look like in the AI space, the intersection of AI and neuroscience, and why AI assistants aren&rsquo;t turning into Terminators anytime soon.]]></description>
      <dc:creator><![CDATA[Eira May]]></dc:creator>
      <category><![CDATA[podcast]]></category>
      <category><![CDATA[ai-assistant]]></category>
      <category><![CDATA[ai]]></category>
      <category><![CDATA[se-tech]]></category>
      <category><![CDATA[se-stackoverflow]]></category>
  </item>
```

Comment: The problem is the `&rsquo;` html character in the title. Seems to be a common problem with rss since it's based on xml which doesn't handle the `&` well.

Comment: The last one I have ([Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird) (works great except very poor usability) as an RSS reader) is ***"Cloudflare Workers have a new skill: AI inference-as-a-service"*** (a podcast episode. 2023-11-21). RSS feed URL: `https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3`

Comment: cont'  - Isn't that the last one?

Comment: What RSS reader, feed URL, etc. do you use? What is the last one that worked (incl. date and URL for the blog post)? Can you [add](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/427304/edit) details to the question? (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now)

Comment: *[Cloudflare Workers have a new skill: AI inference-as-a-service](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/11/21/cloudflare-workers-have-a-new-skill-ai-inference-as-a-service/)* reference (2023-11-21).

Comment: Thunderbird's reader also got the newer 2023-11-28 post (*"[Can GenAI 10X developer productivity?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/11/28/can-genai-10x-developer-productivity/?cb=1)"*). But not [the newest](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/11/29/how-to-scale-a-business-ready-ai-platform-with-watsonx-q-and-a-with-ibm/) from today. Perhaps the information in the RSS feed is only updated once per day?

Answer (score 3):

XML only pre-defines the character entities `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;`, and `&quot;`. Since the RSS DTD does not define any additional character entities, these 5 are the only ones that can be used.

So, this is indeed a bug in the feed. The correct title for that feed entry should be one of these three:

- `<title>The AI assistant trained on your company’s data</title>`,
- `<title>The AI assistant trained on your company&#x2019;s data</title>`, or
- `<title>The AI assistant trained on your company&#8217;s data</title>`.

I mean, what's the point of declaring the encoding of the feed as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and then not using UTF-8?

Comment: The example in the question is from 2023-11-17. I got the newest blog post, 2023-11-21, in [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird) (it has a great built-in RSS reader (though [the usability is atrocious](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/05/15/get-the-feed-url-from-existing-rss-feeds-in-thunderbird/) - very unintuitive. You essentially have to write your own manual to use it effectively (the official documentation is severely lacking))). Perhaps the Thunderbird RSS reader is more tolerant of deviations?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if that encoded form of the quote is simply data being spewed into the XML as-is. That's how it was stored. And perhaps there was even a secondary assumption tagged onto it that if you wrap something in a CDATA block, you'd be safe from XML's earthshattering strictness :) I once had to consume the XML feed from a digital TV guide service which combined data from different other streams. Literally the worst thing I ever had to do.